# Link Running External Docker to docker-compose services

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins, docker-compose, docker-network, docker-container

I assume that there is a way to link via one or a combination of the following: links, external_links and networking.

Any ideas? I have come up empty handed so far.

Here is an example snippet of a Docker-compose which is started from within a separate Ubuntu docker

```
version: '2'
 services:
  web:
   build: .
   depends_on:
    - redis
 redis:
  image: redis
```

I want to be able to connect to the redis port from the Docker that launched the docker-compose.

I do not want to bind the ports on the host as it means I won't be able to start multiple docker-compose from the same model.

-- context --
I am attempting to run a docker-compose from within a Jenkins maven build Docker so that I can run tests. But I cannot for the life of me get the original Docker to access exposed ports on the docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

Reference the machines by hostname, v2 automatically connects the nodes by hostname on a private network by default. You'll be able to ping "web" and "redis" from within each container. If you want to access the machines from your host, include a "ports" definition for each service in your yml.

The v1 links were removed from the v2 compose syntax since they are now implicit. From the [docker compose file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

> **links** with environment variables: As documented in the environment variables reference, environment variables created by links have been
>   deprecated for some time. In the new Docker network system, they have
>   been removed. You should either connect directly to the appropriate
>   hostname or set the relevant environment variable yourself...

Comment: I have updated the description as it was not so obvious what I am doing. From inside an already running Ubuntu docker, I need to start a docker compose which will start from the yaml above. That same Ubuntu docker then needs to access the redis which is inside of the docker-compose's network. I also do NOT want to bind to the entire host, I want to bridge a network connection between the two networks.

Comment: I haven't done the docker inside of docker yet, but have changed the $DOCKER_HOST to access a remote docker host before, which is the same as passing `-H http://host_ip:2375` to the docker commands. That would let you compose your test machine on an isolated network on the same host as the other docker machines.